# Need Help in fade in effect in a video by ffmpeg in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to give fade - in effect in Node js by ffmpeg. I have tried but cant get this. Need help to give this effect in a video.

My code :

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg('public/'+req.body.video)
.videoFilters('fade=in:0:60')
.output('public/videos/test/test.mp4')
.on('end', function(err) {   
    if(!err)
    {
      console.log('conversion marge ended');

    }                 

})
.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('error: '+err);

}).run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg('public/'+req.body.video)
    .videoFilters('fade=in:0:200')
    .output('public/videos/test.mp4')

    .on('end', function(err) {
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log('Effect Done');

        }

    })
    .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('error: '+err);

    }).run();
```